# Нужно поправить разметку шаблона

Tags: шаблоны

Вносил коррективы в шаблон сайта: fitness-nutrition.by. В частности в шапку скопировал и вставил код виджета фильтра по брендам. Вместо фильтра по категориям для поиска (это было по умолчанию в шаблоне). Фильтр работает. Но элементы: Каталог-Бренды-поиск-Впишите-Искать не расположились в одну строку. А должны быть в одной строке друг за другом. Подкажите, как расположить их в одной строке? Что я сделал не так? Как поправить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.<.div. class="header-line-search row visible".>. этому элементу дай класс содержащий:

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

и этому: .<.div class="header-search-form col-md-10".>.

Точки у кода потому что тут html элементы отображаются не так а потом бери все свои 5 блоков верха 100% дели на 5 и каждому блоку дай свою ширину и ровняй все    блоки так что бы в итоге у тебя все 5 блоков в сумме давали width: 100%;.

Этот способ работает на вашем сайте но мне пришлось больше 10 кликов сделать поэтому пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Вроде, все сделал. Но пока не стало на место. Не гляните, что не так? Спасибо.

Comment: М.б. дело еще в одном блоке на этом ряду - мы в соц сетях. Он сделан по умолчанию в шаблоне. Я отключил его когда правил шаблон (есть функция отключения в смс). Но, сейчас включил. Т.к. м.б. это в этом шестом блоке все дело. Его можно убрать. Я плагином добавил соц сети внизу. Ширину отдельных блоков ставил разную. В т.ч. совсем маленькую. Строка все равно не становится, как надо.

Comment: .<.div. class="header-search-form col-md-10".>. этому блоку тоже ставьте: display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;

Comment: Ставил так сразу. И сейчас вернул. Не помогло...

Comment: поставьте сейчас я напишу что дальше

Comment: я поставил. вместо: header-search-form col-md-10 написал: header-search-form. И все стало на место! Сейчас подравняю блоки по ширине страницы. Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Теперь еще вопрос! уж, извините! версию для ПК я сейчас подправлю. А вот мобильна версия не получается. там 3 ряда становятся по вертикали. Нужно чтобы было 2 ряда: каталог (сверху) и Бренды-поиск-впишите-искать - второй ряд (ниже). Как это сделать?

Comment: В общем, нужно, чтобы эти блоки уменьшались по ширине при изменении экрана. А сейчас при уменьшении экрана они выстраиваются в 2 ряда друг под друга.

Comment: я поэтому и говорю вам поставьте флекс везде где я указал

Comment: Добрый день) Есть желание продолжить? или заняты?

Comment: Давайте продолжим

Comment: Добрый день. Я почти все сделал. Более-менее. Есть один не решенный вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста: http://fitness-nutrition.by/ Поле: Впишите (для поиска)+кнопка ПОИСК должны стоять правее по правому краю слайдера. А они туда не становятся. Поле Впишите я хочу увеличить в длинну и сделать такой же длинны, как две кнопки левее. Но, если я увеличиваю ее длину процентами или пикселями, или паддингами, то кнопка ПОИСК съезжает вниз, а не двигается вправо. Т.е. справа что-то мешает. Ну и при этом все кнопки должны быть резиновыми. Т.е. уменьшаться на мобиле. Спсибо!

Comment: Добрый день! Извините за беспокойство снова... Осталась небольшая проблемка. Сайт: fitness-nutrition.by. С версией на ПК все норм. Но на мобильной версии кнопка ПОИСК отображается не корректно. А именно: не на всю ширину, которая ей отведена. Ее нужно просто сделать чуть шире. Если я меняю ее процентами или паддингами, то нарушается соотношение на версии ПК. Можно поправить это?